# $f$ is continuous at point $a$ iff $\lim_{h\to0}f(a+h)-f(a)=0$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, proof-verification, continuity, definition

$$\lim_{h\to0}f(a+h)-f(a)=0\leftrightarrow \lim_{x\to a}f(x)=f(a)$$

Proof.

$\Rightarrow:$

Assume

$$\forall \varepsilon>0,\exists\delta>0,s.t.0<|\color{blue}{h}|<\delta\rightarrow |f(a+\color{blue}{h})-f(a)|<\varepsilon$$

Show

$$\forall \varepsilon>0,\exists\delta>0,s.t.0<|x-a|<\delta\rightarrow |f(x)-f(a)|<\varepsilon$$

Let $h:=x-a$ that by assumption we have

$$\forall \varepsilon>0,\exists\delta>0,s.t.0<|\color{blue}{x-a}|<\delta\rightarrow |f(a+\color{blue}{x-a})-f(a)|<\varepsilon$$

$$\forall \varepsilon>0,\exists\delta>0,s.t.0<|\color{blue}{x-a}|<\delta\rightarrow |f(x)-f(a)|<\varepsilon$$

$\Leftarrow:$

Assume

$$\forall \varepsilon>0,\exists\delta>0,s.t.0<|\color{blue}{x-a}|<\delta\rightarrow |f(x)-f(a)|<\varepsilon$$

Show

$$\forall \varepsilon>0,\exists\delta>0,s.t.0<|h|<\delta\rightarrow |f(a+h)-f(a)|<\varepsilon$$

Let $x-a:=h$ by assumption we have

$$\forall \varepsilon>0,\exists\delta>0,s.t.0<|\color{blue}{x-a}|<\delta\rightarrow |f(a+\color{blue}{x-a})-f(a)|<\varepsilon$$

$$\forall \varepsilon>0,\exists\delta>0,s.t.0<|\color{blue}{h}|<\delta\rightarrow |f(a+\color{blue}{h})-f(a)|<\varepsilon\tag*{$\square$}$$

---

I saw some notes state that $\lim_{h\to0}f(a+h)-f(a)=0$ implies continuous, but i

don't know this alternative definition before, so i'm tring to prove this.

the proof seems like just plug in some variables to the limit-definition

Is this correct, thanks for your help.

Comment: Try to prove the following: if $f$ has limit $L$ at $a$, then $f + c$ has limit $L + c$ at $a.$ (*Hint:* if you wrote more than 2 lines, you are already lost.) Having it, apply it to the particular case $L = f(a).$

Comment: Some general comments: avoid using $\forall, \exists$ in actual proofs, unless your proof is directly related to first-order logic or something. Often when students are introduced to proofs, they get this idea that using logical symbols is somehow more rigorous. It isn't. Human languages convey ideas much better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have that the two statements are equivalent, indeed

$$\lim_{h\to0}f(a+h)-f(a)=0 \iff\lim_{h\to0}f(a+h)=f(a)$$

and by $x=a+h \to a$

$$\lim_{h\to0}f(a+h)=f(a) \iff \lim_{x\to a}f(x)=f(a)$$

that is the [**definition**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_function#Definition_in_terms_of_limits_of_functions) of continuous function.